# Are there any Bitwise Operator Laws?

Tags: computer-science, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, proof

Thinking in terms of Algebraic laws, I was wondering if there are any official guide lines which exist in the realm of bit manipulations, similar to Algebra.

**Algebraic Example**

`a - b =/= b - a`

Let `a = 7` and `b = 5`

- `a - b = 2`
- `b - a = -2`

Let `a = 10` and `b = 3`

- `a - b = 7`
- `b - a = -7`

Thus `if a > b`, `b - a` will be the negative equivalent to `a - b`. Because of this, we *can* say 
`|a - b| = |b - a|`.

Where `|x|` denotes the absolute value of `x`.

**Bitwise Example**

`a | b =/= a + b`

```
      00001010 = 10
  OR  00000101 = 5 
  -----------------
      00001111 = 15
```

Note the unsigned byte manipulation: `10 | 5 = 15`, which is synonymous with `10 + 5 = 15`

However, if both `a` and `b` equal 5 and we `OR` them, the result would be 5, because `a = b`, which means we're just comparing the same exact bits with each other, thus resulting in nothing new.

Likewise, if `b = 7`, `a = 10` and we `OR` them we'll have 15. This is because

```
    00001010 = 10
 OR 00000111 = 7
 -----------------
    00001111 = 15
```

So, we can effectively conclude that `a | b =/= a + b`.

Comment: This one is a must have: http://books.google.ch/books?id=f83XxoBC_8MC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=linda+null+boolean+algebra&source=bl&ots=5ekB3gV6Y1&sig=p5syOlOTWGbt-PN-T1fuiS2LYnk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jrpwUKHIAez64QTK_YGoDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=linda%20null%20boolean%20algebra&f=false

Comment: This contains most of the useful things you can do with bitwise operators: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: Thank you. If either of you post an answer I'll gladly accept :)

Comment: hacker's delight, is a great book to have also

Answer (score 58):

Bitwise operations that are just a boolean operator applied between corresponding bits of the operands follow laws analogous to the laws of Boolean algebra, for example:

- `AND (&)` : Commutative, Associative, Identity (0xFF), Annihilator (0x00), Idempotent
- `OR  (|)` : Commutative, Associative, Identity (0x00), Annihilator (0xFF), Idempotent
- `XOR (^)` : Commutative, Associative, Identity (0x00), Inverse (itself)
- `NOT (~)` : Inverse (itself)

AND and OR absorb each other:

- `a & (a | b) = a`
- `a | (a & b) = a`

There are some pairs of distributive operators, such as:

- AND over OR: `a & (b | c) = (a & b) | (a & c)`
- AND over XOR: `a & (b ^ c) = (a & b) ^ (a & c)`
- OR over AND: `a | (b & c) = (a | b) & (a | c)`

Note however that XOR does not distribute over AND or OR, and neither does OR distribute over XOR.

DeMorgans law applies in its various forms:

- `~(a & b) = ~a | ~b`
- `~(a | b) = ~a & ~b`

Some laws that relate XOR and AND can be found by reasoning about the field ℤ/2ℤ, in which addition corresponds to XOR and multiplication to AND:

- AND distributes over XOR
- Working out products of sums: `(a ^ b) & (c ^ d) = (a & c) ^ (a & d) ^ (b & c) ^ (b & d)`

There are some laws that combine arithmetic and bitwise operations:

- Subtract by adding: `a - b = ~(~a + b)`
- Add carries separately: `a + b = (a ^ b) + ((a & b) << 1)`
- Turn `min` into `max` and vice versa: `min(a, b) = ~max(~a, ~b)`, `max(a, b) = ~min(~a, ~b)`

Shifts have no inverse because of the "destruction" of bits pushed to the edge

`left shift  (<<)` : Associative, Distributive, Identity (0x00)

`right shift (>>)` : Associative, Distributive, Identity (0x00)

`rotate left  (rl)` : Associative, Distributive, Identity (0x00), Inverse (`rr`)

`rotate right (rr)` : Associative, Distributive, Identity (0x00), Inverse (`rl`)

While shifts have no inverse, some expressions involving shifts do have inverses as consequence of other laws, for example:

- `x + (x << k)` has an inverse, because it is effectively a multiplication by an odd number and odd numbers have an modular multiplicative inverse modulo a power of two. For `x + (x << 1) = x * 3`, the inverse is `x * 0xAAAAAAAB` (for 32 bits, adjust the constant for other sizes)
- `x ^ (x << k)` has an inverse for a similar reason, but through the correspondence with carryless multiplication.
- Similarly `x ^ (x >> k)` (with unsigned right shift) has an inverse, it's just the "mirror image" of the above.

Comment: I don't see more properties, Commutative indicating commutativity. And I can't quite wrap my head around distributivity for non-shifting operators. I nonetheless extended the shift operators as they are distributive for all other operations

Comment: Yes ok, well I'll post some more I guess

Comment: I can get this answer as a Community wiki, so you can edit it quickly. It doesn't matter if I don't own this badly incomplete answer

Comment: Very complete summary of the properties, the only thing I can see that you missed mentioning is bitwise rotations. Well done!

Comment: got exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What is an annihilator?

Comment: left shift  (<<) : Associative, Distributive, Identity (0x00)

 is wrong i think because a<<(b<<c) == (a<<b)<<c returns false

Comment: `a + b = (a | b) + (a & b)` is another nice one